# What happened to Bruno Pereira?

Tags: discussion

[image]

[image]

What happened to Bruno?

Where is his moderator diamond? Will it be given back?

Comment: @BrunoPereira - I hope things are OK w/ you please be well!

Comment: This question is not to be featured, as it is disrespectful to the moderator in question. It has been closed as it is the only way to unfeature this. For more details see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He might have resigned from being a moderator, this may be more likely as it is harder to be manually removed.

I imagine he probably needed time to take care of personal matters.

> Bruno wanted to take some time off to take care of things. Some R&R time if you will
>
> – [Mitch ♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch), [from chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14173646#14173646), spelling corrected

Sad to see him missing his diamond, but I'm sure we will see him around still.